mariadb: why does altering a table column from unsigned to signed int (or the reverse) require the COPY algorithm?
I have database table with a tens of millions of records. For some reason the auto increment id column is a signed int and I tried to change it to an unsigned int. Goes without saying but I checked there are no negative values in that column.
I tried to use the following statement:
ALTER TABLE `table` 
MODIFY COLUMN `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ALGORITHM INSTANT, 
LOCK = NONE; 

which was unsuccessful due to it requiring the COPY algorithm
ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported. Reason: Cannot change column type. Try 
ALGORITHM=COPY

Since the table is quite large (~15gb data + 15gb indexes) the COPY algorithm would take a long time during which the table would lock.
I would assume, that only meta data would be modified, since the storage should not change at all. Both have the same amount of bytes (4) and for positive values the bit-representation should be identical. Everything should be identical.
What's the reason why COPY is the only supported algorithm? Is there any way to achieve this without copying the whole table?

Test what causes INSTANT nonapplicable - the datatype change or the fact that the column is PRIMARY KEY...

Probable reason:  Half of the Signed int values are invalid for Unsigned.  (And vice versa)  So, error checking is needed.

@RickJames thank you. I totally get that checking is needed. since it's also a primary key, the index should quickly find an answer to the question "are there invalid values?" And, while copying the table, what would happen if it encountered an invalid value? It would have to do something, because otherwise if (raw) data isn't changed, why even start copying? the longer I think about it, the less it makes sense, unless there is simply no nuance in the modify-column algorithm in regards to what data types can be losslessly interpreted as certain other data types if certain checks pass.

@jtopt - The developers haven't thought of check first, then let INSTANT work.  This is one of a dozen special cases that would take extra effort for rare errors.  For the first 20 years of MySQL/MariaDB, the only ALTER method was "copy".
